# DialogFlow v2 fulfillmentMessages

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, api-ai

I'm trying to respond to users with news cards but as far as I can see if I follow your example it does not work.
If I just respond with fulfillmentMessages like this

```
res.json({
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "card": {
          "title": "card title",
          "subtitle": "card text",
          "imageUri": "https://assistant.google.com/static/images/molecule/Molecule-Formation-stop.png",
          "buttons": [
            {
              "text": "button text",
              "postback": "https://assistant.google.com/"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "source": "example.com"
});
```

I get this error back:

```
{
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "code": 13,
      "message": "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response",
      "details": [
        {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Value",
          "value": "{\"id\":\"ef8154ae-96ff-4837-b7e7-d3388223240d\",\"timestamp\":\"2018-04-27T15:19:19.449Z\",\"lang\":\"en-us\",\"result\":{},\"status\":{\"code\":200,\"errorType\":\"success\"},\"sessionId\":\"1524841118917\"}"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If I add the fulfillmentText (that should be optional) Google Assistant will only use the plain text as a response and won't use cards.

Has someone fixed this issue?

Comment: You need to add a simple response. Where are you using your action that you don't see your card?

Comment: I was testing from the assistant console (not the dialogflow one)

Comment: Have you tested on a phone to see if the behavior is the same?

Comment: yes, it always return the simple text and I can't find a way on documentation/example that's working